Registering and using JDBC driver in Groovy Console
I am new to Groovy and need some help in creating a script that connects to Databricks using a JDBC driver.  What I have is...
// Import the Groovy class required to work with SQL databases
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.sql.DataSet
import java.sql.*

//Register driver --have tried both of these options separately with no success
//DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver())
//Class.forName('com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver')

// Set up database connection properties
def url = 'jdbc:databricks://<<databricks server info>>:443' 
def user = 'username'
def password = 'pwd'
def driver = 'com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver'


// Connect to the SQL instance
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)

After reading numerous posts on this and other sites, I have the environment variable CLASSPATH defined as the folder structure on my local system to the databricks JDBC .jar file, and ASSUME I'm correctly defining 'driver' per the documentation on the DataBricks site.  However, without the two lines to register the driver I get the message, "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver".  Using the register line, "DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver())" I get the exception message "unable to resolve class com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver", and using the register line "Class.forName(com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver)" I get the exception message "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: ConsoleScript21" or "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver"
I want to understand how to register the JDBC driver and how 'com.databricks.client.jdbc42.Driver' tells the script where to find the driver on my system (and feel free to talk to me like I'm a 4-year old so I understand it in its most basic level).
I have looked at the post What is classpath for Groovy Console / jdbc driver prblem?, but was not able to solve my problem.

How do you add the databrick dependency with the driver?

Not sure I understand your question, which should be a clue on how little I know on this!     So here goes my best shot.  For the line "jdbc:databricks://", I pulled that from an automated test tool, that utilizes Groovy, in one of their connection templates for DataBricks.  Any other reference to 'databricks' was pulled from documentation on the DataBricks site, or posts on StackOverflow.  Hope that answers your question.

That driver class will be in a library (jar file). How are you adding that jar file to your class path?

Through the Envornment Variables screen from Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings

not sure where did you take 42 in jdbc class  name...
according to documentation the classname should be: com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver
code that is loading jdbc driver:
@Grab(group='com.databricks', module='databricks-jdbc', version='2.6.36')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)

def cl = Class.forName('com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver')

Parameters for Grab you can search by a classname: https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver
It's very important to use @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true) - it makes jar to be loaded under system classloader which makes it visible for jdbc driver manager.

"not sure where did you take 42 in jdbc class name" ChatGPT got confused with postgres...

Thanks for including the links in your comment daggett!  I'll read up on the info shortly.  The information I found was in the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_extras/documents/databricks-jdbc-driver-install-and-configuration-guide.pdf on page 11.  The version I downloaded was 42, and that doc gives the example for registering the connector class.  I will try removing '42' in my code and see what happens next.  Thanks again!
